# Nginx rewrite multiple locations

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'd like to rewrite specific locations to `https` like here:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root   /var/www/$server_name/public;
    #error_log /error.logg debug;
    error_page 403 /403.html;
    location  = /403.html {
        allow all;
    }
    location / {
        #allow xxx.xxx.xxx;
        #deny all;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /register {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
    location /login {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
}
```

`/register` and `/login` are not the only places i'll need to write, so how would I deal with multiple locations without having the repeat the location block for each place I want to rewrite to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression location match, like this:

```
location ~ ^/(login|register) {
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri?$args permanent;
}
```